# Rails: Undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ApplicationController, there is `current_use`.

```
 private

  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !!session[:user_id]
  end
```

`logged_in?` and authenticate works. However, when I change

```
<% if logged_in? %>
```

to

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user.free? %>
```

in views/top/index.html.erb, following error occurs.

```
NameError at /

undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:...>:...>
```

How do I solve this?

`free?` is defined in user.rb as

```
def free?
  visit.game.count == 0
end
```

**Added**

If I change `current_user` to `@current_user`, error message become as follows.

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `free?' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try and add this to your application controller:

```
helper_method :current_user
```

What this does is that it makes the private method as a helper method and it is accessible in all the controllers and views. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why does it work then for his **logged_in?** method?

Comment: just once try and remove the logged_in method from the controller and see if it works or not. Because what I suspect is that you are using any gem which is providing you the method.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I wrote "helper_method :logged_in" as my book instracts but I didn't understand that very well. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when working on a **Rails 6** API only application with the **Pundit** gem and the **JWT** gem for authentication.

I was running into this error when trying to test a **Pundit** authorization for a controller action:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #Api::V1::SchoolsController:0x00007f30a4918120\nDid you mean?  @current_user

**Here's how I fixed**:

The `current_user` method seemed unavailable to **Pundit** so it was throwing that error when it could not find it.

I simply defined a `pundit_user` in the `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Pundit

  def pundit_user
    header = request.headers['Authorization']
    header = header.split(' ').last if header
    @decoded = JsonWebToken.decode(header)
    User.find(@decoded[:user_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
    rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
      render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
  end
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**